# Drawing image with subscript and superscript in php

Tags: php, image, subscript, superscript

Can somebody help me I am trying to draw a mathematical image in php with subscripts and superscripts. [image: mathematical image]

This is my idea.

Comment: Can you post your code as well?

Comment: You want to hear about TeX.

Comment: I am not getting any idea to make this